# How to use datepickerdialog inside custom dialog

Tags: android, datepicker, dialog, listener, customdialog

I want to use datepickerdialo when user click on editext in the dialog.
I made custom dialog like this

[image]

I need to show datepickerdialo after clicking on editext

here is custom dialog XML code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/dialog_start_time"
            android:id="@+id/dialog_start_date"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:id="@+id/dpStartDate"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/dialog_end_time"
            android:id="@+id/dialog_end_date"
            android:textSize="18dp"

            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:id="@+id/dpEndDate"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

here is DialogFragment

```
public class CalcDialog extends DialogFragment{
final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
final int startYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
final int startMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
final int startDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final Dialog dialog;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_calc_dialog, null);
    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_calc_dialog, null))
            // Add action buttons

            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // sign in the user ...

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    CalcDialog.this.getDialog().cancel();
                }
            }).setTitle("Period");
    dialog = builder.create();
    EditText startDateEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.dpStartDate);
    startDateEditText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new DatePickerDialog(dialog.getContext(), listener1, startYear, startMonth, startDay).show();
        }
    });


    return dialog;

}
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener1 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

    }
};
}
```

Please answer clearly as I am beginner

Comment: What's the exact problem? Also, this is not a good idea from UX point of view.. Why do you need this intermediate "Period" dialog? I think it'd be better to show date picker right away.

Comment: I need to show datepicker dialog after clicking on editext. I tried to use two datepicker directly in the custom dialog but the dialog was too big (at least for me) @Gennadii Saprykin

Comment: is your view DatePicker view returning null

Answer (score -1):

You need to change this

```
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_calc_dialog, null))
```

to

```
builder.setView(view)
```